# Interbase Error: SQLDA missing or incorrect version, or incorrect number/type of variables

Tags: sql, delphi, interbase, bde

I get this error on many of the `TQuery` connected to Interbase via BDE. Exact message is:

> General SQL Error. Dynamic SQL Error, SQL error code = -804, SQLDA missing or incorrect version, or incorrect number/type of variables.

The message appears as soon as I try to open/edit the `TQuery` at design time, or when a Post is done at run time. For the Post action at run time, I have found that if I Prepare the table before the Post, the Post is done nicely.

I have read [Craig Stunz's Weblog about same error](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/sqlda-missing-or-incorrect-version-or-incorrect-numbertype-of-variables-37934). The parameters I have are all integers. Database is small, Interbase 2009, and I see no particular patterns with the queries that show the error message (it can be selected, deleted, updated etc.). Running the query out of Delphi is just fine.

The tables have numeric data type (15,2).

The tables have been backup/restored from Interbase version 5 - dialect 1 to Interbase 2009.

Actual ODS is 13.1 (Interbase 9).

No UDFs.

Any idea what is wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

Samples of query not showing the error / showing the error:

**No Error:**

```
select MASTER_ID, GL_ACCT_DR, GL_ACCT_CR,
VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_CODE,
ORDER_NO, ORDER_DATE, INVOICE_NO, INVOICE_DATE,
DESCRIP, BUYER, SHIP_VIA, FOB, IS_FREIGHT_PREPAID,
IS_TAXABLE, TERMS_ID, TERMS_CODE,
DISC_DAYS_OR_DATE, DISCOUNT_PCT, NET_DAYS_OR_DATE,
BILL_TO_LOC_ID, SHIP_TO_LOC_ID,
BILL_TO_LOC_CODE, SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE,
DISCOUNT_DATE, DUE_DATE
from P_JRNTRN where
ENTITY_DB_ID = :PRIMARY_DB_ID and
SRC_MODULE = 'PJ'
order by INVOICE_NO
```

Parameter is Integer.

**Error:**

```
select * from P_JRNTRN where
BATCH_ID = :BATCH_ID
order by MASTER_ID
```

Parameter is Integer.

**[UPDATE] ... 
I've not been able to resolved this problem so i moved to IBDAC in replacement of the BDE. I get no more error. 
Thanks to all.**

Comment: Can you post a sample query? I've had trouble with this error in the past, long time ago, but I'm struggling to remember what the issue was. I had a feeling we were seeing it with a character-set mismatch but I guess that's not the case for you.

Comment: Character-set is default. I know i have few field-type mismatch (translation form interbase 5 t0 9). I will post some sample query - thanks.

Comment: Ah, thanks for posting the edit. Are there any other fields in that table (thinking about difference between select * and select [named])? Can you post the schema for that table? We had a problem with older Interbase and long field/sproc names, that caused it to do weird, unexpected things but again don't think that's the problem here (something about only using the first 12 chars, but my memory is poor). Don't see why that would work in old Interbase and not in new Interbase though - more likely to be the other way around!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using DataDirect ODBC InterBase driver.

When I switched to the official Firebird ODBC driver, I solved it.

Comment: @EduardoCuomo, I'm sorry, but I can't even remember the application where I stumbled upon this error...